# Changing captions on DateTime Picker dialog

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

In the DateTimePicker, when the App is in portuguese, the word "Confirmar" (default) doesn't fit the button in some devices.
Is it possible to change it?

[image]

Comment: comment removed : did not see this was about genexus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change this text directly in the Language object (Portuguese) and it will be used on the next Build/Run. It's the translation for the **GXM_button_ok** literal.

For the record, the three literals are:

- GXM_button_ok
- GXM_Now
- GXM_cancel

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change it. The only solution to it, is that you should create a custom dialog with the date, time pickers and buttons, and adjust the buttons in it properly. Its strange that this issue exists in the native android source code!

Comment: In native android, you can quite easily change the text of such buttons.

Comment: But then you will have to build the android source code with your changes and tell people to put that changed android build on their phones right? Which I don't think is quite easy.

Comment: What? no! You'd simply have to access the buttons of the dialog, and change the text to whatever suits you.

Comment: no. There are 3 buttons here. In the example of a `DatePickerDialog`, you would simply do `dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText("Whatever");`.

Comment: Oh got it, I totally misunderstood! Thanks a lot for the info.